# MFMailComposeViewController and statusBar problem

Tags: ios4

I have an `UIViewController` with its view manually added to another view.

When I display `MFMailComposeViewController` modally using :

```
[self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
```

And then remove it, my view which presents the mail composer gets it's Y origin changed to 20. (Status bar height)

I am unable to find why. Do you have an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: @thierrb : I am facing same problem. Did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I came across this problem myself. Not sure why this happens but what worked for me was putting the following in the viewWillAppear method of the controller that presented the modal view:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

Comment: Thank you! You just saved me from a great deal of hacking. FWIW, the 'wantsFullScreenLayout' alone seems to have done it for me.

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me was putting

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

right after presenting the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

on

```
  viewDidLoad().
```

This will keep your UI under the status bar.

Unless you want to completely hide the status bar, so you should go with crinkle's answer